# How to save the state of Agenda buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

What I mean:

Each of us has his own commands set in `org-agenda-custom-commands` variable.
But how can I detect what commands were used to create the current state of Agenda buffer (looking only at this buffer, maybe any local varibales?).

I want to save it and recreate later without dependence on current `.emacs` configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun wg-get-org-agenda-view-commands ()
  "Get commands by which the current state of Agenda buffer can
be restored using \"(eval commands)\"."
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer org-agenda-buffer-name)
      (with-current-buffer org-agenda-buffer-name
        (let* ((p (or (and (looking-at "\\'") (1- (point))) (point)))
               (series-redo-cmd (get-text-property p 'org-series-redo-cmd)))
          (if series-redo-cmd
              (get-text-property p 'org-series-redo-cmd)
            (get-text-property p 'org-redo-cmd))))))

(defun wg-run-agenda-cmd (f)
  "Run commands \"f\" in Agenda buffer. You can get these
commands using \"wg-get-org-agenda-view-commands\"."
  (if (get-buffer org-agenda-buffer-name)
      (save-window-excursion
        (with-current-buffer org-agenda-buffer-name
          (let* ((line (org-current-line)))
            (if f (eval f))
            (org-goto-line line))))))
```

Just read doc strings for both functions.
Thanks to fellas on org-mode mailing list. They gave me a hint.

Now I continue "workgroups" extension - [workgroups2](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2) which can save and restore org-agenda buffer.